# Replace spaces by tab

Tags: r

I did an analysis in R with the package 'indicspecies',

```
indval.ch <- multipatt(species.indval, samples.indval, duleg = FALSE)
summary(indval.ch)
```

by the output is like this

```
Multilevel pattern analysis
 ---------------------------

 Association function: IndVal.g
 Significance level (alpha): 0.05

 Total number of species: 910
 Selected number of species: 183 
 Number of species associated to 1 group: 125 
 Number of species associated to 2 groups: 58 

 List of species associated to each combination: 

 Group estromatolito  #sps.  8 
                             stat p.value   
Candidatus_Methylomirabilis 0.967   0.005 **
Subgroup_26                 0.943   0.015 * 
Fimbriimonadales            0.787   0.025 * 
Methyloceanibacter          0.745   0.035 * 
Subgroup_13                 0.716   0.035 * 
Pseudofulvimonas            0.667   0.040 * 
IheB2.23                    0.577   0.050 * 
SZB85                       0.577   0.040 * 

 Group suelo  #sps.  86 
                                                    stat p.value   
Acidothermus                                       1.000   0.005 **
Geodermatophilus                                   1.000   0.005 **
Angustibacter                                      1.000   0.005 **
Oryzihumus                                         1.000   0.005 **
Actinoplanes                                       1.000   0.005 **
Dactylosporangium                                  1.000   0.005 **
Segetibacter                                       1.000   0.005 **
YC.ZSS.LKJ147                                      1.000   0.005 **
```

I mean, R shows me different matrix in function of the analysis I made. I need each data frame in order to visualize that results, I tried to extract each group and I searched some codes for that, but it seems not possible. For that reason I think I could copy-paste the results but each element is separated by different number of spaces.
Is it possible replace the spaces by a tab? It is a bit hard to do that manually.

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Please provide the coee you are running, not just the result + a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I discourage the assumption that you have to parse the output of an R package in order to get the data structures you think you need. Look instead at the structure of the output and/or at the related function calls to get the *data* you need without inferential parsing. Why? (1) Parsing output is lossy, e.g., `0.967` could really be `0.9665-0.9674`; (2) whatever is determined here might be regex-based, which is powerful ... and at times, fragile. When you look at your model, realize that there is likely a `print.*` S3 method being used to show you this from a well-structured `list` of stats.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the function you are using is `multipatt` from that package.

The help page is realtively clear. So you'll probably get a list with different elements (matrices) in it.

Depending on how you name the result obect for your analysis, you can access them via e.g.:

```
my_results_comb <- YOURRESULTSOBJECTNAME$comb
my_results_str  <- YOURRESULTSOBJECTNAME$str
```

If need be you can convert both objects to data frame by wrapping them with a `as.data.frame` command.

Comment: yes, I used 'multipatt', but I asked the 'summary()', in order to obtain the matrix with stats and p-value by site, when I run 'my_results_str  <- YOURRESULTSOBJECTNAME$str', R shows me all the data.

Comment: You can use the same rationale with the summary function. First check 'names(summary(yourresults))' and them try to access the required objects with sth. like 'summary$xxx'. xxx being the name of the part of summary that you want to access.